# subsetting an ltraj object based on a threshold value

Tags: r

I am working with animal trajectories in the R package adehabitatLT.
This package stores animal trajectories as `ltraj` objects, and contains the function `cutltraj` that allows you to divide an animal's trajectory into different segments based on some criterion.

```
cutltraj(ltraj, criterion)
```

where the `criterion` is a character string giving any syntactically correct R logical expression implying the descriptive parameters in x. The example in the vignette section is:

```
foo <- function(dt) {
       return(dt> (100*3600*24))
       }

newltraj <- cutltraj(bear, "foo(dt)", nextr = TRUE)
```

I would like to segment my animal trajectory, but I need help writing an expression to feed into the `criterion` arguement.
I would like a new segment to be created anytime the value of `myltraj$dist` between successive rows crosses the threshold value of 400.

So, I want a new segment in scenarios where:
1) `myltraj$dist` is <400, and `myltraj$dist` at nrow+1 is >400, and
2) `myltraj$dist` is >400, and `myltraj$dist` at nrow+1 is <400

How can I write this as a function?

Comment: Where does `myltraj` get created? We need reproducible data to work with

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `lag()` from dplyr

```
foo<-function(dist) {
    return(dist>=400 & lag(dist<400) | dist<400 & lag(dist>=400))
    }
```

`myltraj` is the name of the ltraj object containing my data.

`cutltraj(ltraj, "foo(dist)", nextr = TRUE))`